# How make directory to file in HDFS Hadoop (Cloudera) java

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I first work with Hadoop assembly Cloudera. I need to make directory to file in Linux server with HDFS.

But when I use java in cmd Linux it not create directory, but create file.

Can you help me what i do bad can you me explain, near my code java to create directory in hdfs and file.Thank your. Sorry for bad English.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileDemo {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean success = false;

    System.out.println("Enter path of directory to create");
    String dir = reader.nextLine();

    // Creating new directory in Java, if it doesn't exists
    File directory = new File(dir);
    if (directory.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Directory already exists ...");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Directory not exists, creating now");

        success = directory.mkdir();
        if (success) {
            System.out.printf("Successfully created new directory : %s%n", dir);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Failed to create new directory: %s%n", dir);
        }
    }

    // Creating new file in Java, only if not exists
    System.out.println("Enter file name to be created ");
    String filename = reader.nextLine();

    File f = new File(filename);
    if (f.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File already exists");

    } else {
        System.out.println("No such file exists, creating now");
        success = f.createNewFile();
        if (success) {
            System.out.printf("Successfully created new file: %s%n", f);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Failed to create new file: %s%n", f);
        }
    }

    // close Scanner to prevent resource leak
    reader.close();
}
}
```

Comment: You want to create a directory on local filesystem or on HDFS? You code does not seem to be creating HDFS directories.. I do not see why it is related to Hadoop..

Comment: I want make directory in HDFS? can you show me how i can do it

Comment: Check https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html class if you would like to do it programatically.

Comment: Check this http://mund-consulting.com/Blog/file-operations-in-hdfs-using-java/

Answer (score 0):

When I want to make a directory on HDFS, I do so from the command line. Try this at your command prompt

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /input
```

That should create a folder in HDFS called input.

From [this site](https://tutorials.techmytalk.com/2014/08/16/hadoop-hdfs-java-api/), I found this

```
URI uri=URI.create (“hdfs://host: port/path”);
```

which I believe should create the directory for you.

Comment: i new that can do it in cmd but i need it from java?can your help

Comment: @MattCremeens your solution (with URI) might not work if the cluster is secured.

Comment: @Serhiy I guess we'll see. I believe I've used the solution before in my own hadoop projects. I guess it's up to the OP to try it and see. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /home/hduser/wordcount/input/
```

worked for me